# Backbone / Rails - build(params[...]) raises ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, backbone.js, parameters

I am using backbone and trying to create a new object and I am running into this error.  I thought rails would just ignore attributes that it doesn't care about.  i.e. the authenticity token isnt trying to be added to my object.

My controller:

```
def create
  page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
  branch = page.page_branches.build(params[:page_branch])
  branch.form = page.form
  if branch.valid?
    page.page_branches << branch
    redirect_to(edit_page_path(page, :anchor => "branch-panel"))
  else
    raise "#{branch.errors.map}"
  end
end
```

The Error:

```
Processing by PageBranchesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"page_branch"=>{"next_page_id"=>"KS5ad82889e04e5806e0455d5a81e81a9511",
 "description"=>"linking", "utf8"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"", "id"=>nil,
 "page_id"=>"KS000c29724a16-u-2TQMP57-gYm-U", "trigger_type"=>"Always",
 "base_options"=>"AllowAnonymous;BASE",
 "question_options"=>"KS000c29724a16CfC2TQUL1--gxG-U", "keyword_options"=>"",
 "qualification"=>"", "commit"=>""}, "page_id"=>"KS000c29724a16-u-2TQMP57-gYm-U"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 239ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: utf8):
  app/controllers/page_branches_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Thanks to the response below:

I added the attr_accessible on my rails model:

```
attr_accessible :page_id, :page_name, :next_page_id, :next_page_name,
                :description, :trigger_type, :internal_qualification,
                :order, :form_id, :qualification
```

By doing that, I get the following warnings, but the build succeeds

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: utf8, authenticity_token, id, base_options, question_options, keyword_options, commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord mass assignment is gonna try to use every key/value pair in the hash is provided and *raise* an UnknownAttributeError when [unknown attributes are supplied via mass assignment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeError.html).

Maybe checking out [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L78-90) can help to confirm what I'm saying.

I think you have two options:

1. To clean up the `params[:page_branch]` before use it in the *mass assignment*.
2. Modify the `Backbone.YourModel.toJSON()` to not send weird attributes to the server.